# Access multiple user's Google Fit data from server side periodically

Tags: c#, api, google-fit-api

I am trying to access steps count of all users who are resisted in my website.
I have setup a cronjob every day at a fixed time. I have created a service account credintials and downloaded its json

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GoogleFit(string email)
    {
        var scopes = new[] { FitnessService.Scope.FitnessActivityRead };
        var credentials = GoogleCredential.FromJson(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(jsonPath))
            .CreateScoped(scopes);

        var fitnessService = new FitnessService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credentials,
            ApplicationName = "App name"
        });

        var dataSources = await fitnessService.Users.DataSources.List(email).ExecuteAsync();
        var foundData = dataSources.DataSource.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "raw")?.DataStreamId;
        if (foundData == null)
        {
            return NotFound("No data source");
        }

        var start = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        var end = start.AddDays(1);
        DateTime unixStart = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        long unixTimeStart = (long)(start - unixStart).TotalSeconds;
        long unixTimeEnd = (long)(end - unixStart).TotalSeconds;
        var result = await fitnessService.Users.Dataset.Aggregate(new AggregateRequest()
        {
            AggregateBy = new List<AggregateBy>
                        {
                             new AggregateBy
                                    {
                                         DataSourceId = foundData,
                                         DataTypeName = "com.google.step_count.delta"
                                    }
                         },
            BucketByTime = new BucketByTime
            {
                DurationMillis = 86400000
            },
            StartTimeMillis = unixTimeStart,
            EndTimeMillis = unixTimeEnd

        }, email).ExecuteAsync();
        return Ok(result);
    }
```

This is the api i use to test, when i give a email i get the

```
    The service fitness has thrown an exception.
HttpStatusCode is Forbidden.
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
The caller does not have permission [403]
Errors [
    Message[The caller does not have permission] Location[ - ] Reason[forbidden] Domain[global]
]
```

Also if i pass "me" instead of email in  `var dataSources = await fitnessService.Users.DataSources.List(email).ExecuteAsync();`

i get no error but dataSources count is 0

Comment: ChatGPT said **Unfortunately, it's not possible to access Google Fit data from a server-side application using C#. Google Fit API provides data only through authorized user consent and OAuth 2.0 user authorization. This means that data can only be accessed from the user's device, not from a server.If you need to access fitness data from multiple users, you'll need to have each user authorize your application to access their data, and then retrieve the data individually through the API.**

Comment: is it true? and no work around?